# What is a good way to read in and separate information from this text file?

Tags: c++, file, file-io

Let's say I have a text file:

```
83 71 69 97Joines, William B.
100 85 88 85Henry, Jackson Q.
```

And I want to store each number in an array of ints, and each full-name into an array of strings (a full name would be `Joines, William B` for example).

What would be the best way, because I debated whether using `while (inputFile >> line)` or `while (getline(inputFile, line))` would be better. I don't know if it would be easier to read them one word at a time or read them one line at a time. My main problem will be splitting the `97Joines, William B.` to `97` and `Joines, William B.` which I don't understand how to do in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    int scores[40];
    string names[10];
    string filename, line;
    ifstream inputFile;


cout << "Please enter the location of the file:\n";
cin >> filename;

inputFile.open(filename);
while (inputFile >> line) {
    // if line is numeric values only, do scores[counter] = line;
    // if it is alphabet characters only, do names[counter] = line;
    //if it is both, find a way to split it // <----- need help figuring out how to do this!

}
inputFile.close();
```

}

Comment: The best way is to search stackoverflow for "c++ read file array int" and study the posts.  There are already a plethora of similar questions about how to read in data from a text file.

Comment: A better method is to use a structure or class to model the text line and use a vector of these structures.  Don't use parallel arrays as they are prone to synchronization issues (especially when sorting).

Comment: My main question was about the `97Joines, William B.`, how would I split that up because they get read in as one. It should be `97` and `Joines, William B.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `#include <cstdlib>` for `strtol` I am sure there are better ways to do this but this is the only way I know and this is only for 97joines, and 85Henry,

```
          string word; // to get joines,
          string str; // for 97
          string numword;
          inputFile >> numword;
          for(int k = 0; k < numword.length(); k++)
          {
              if(isdigit(numword[k]))
              {
                 str = str + numword[k];
              }
              else
              {
                word = word + numword[k];
              }
          }
          int num = strtol(str.c_str(), NULL, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, given the file structure you have shown, read it like this:

```
int a, b, c, d;
std::string name;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    // read the numbers
    inputFile >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    // read the name
    std::getline(inputFile, name);

    // do stuff with the data... we just print it now
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << " " << name << std::endl;
}
```

Since the numbers are space separated it is easy to just use the stream operator. Furthermore, since the name is the last part we can just use `std::getline` which will read the rest of the line and store it in the variable `name`.

You can try it [here](http://ideone.com/sVEGc9), using `std::cin`.

Comment: My main question was about the `97Joines, William B.`, how would I split that up because they get read in as one. It should be `97` and `Joines, William B.`

Comment: @StacksAndParsing Fair enough, I mistakenly thought you wanted a alternatively solution.